# Any Quicker Option Than Oracle Database Union

Tags: database, performance, oracle, oracle10g, union

I have a table that has multiple columns which store a text value. For example:

```
ID    FATHER_NAME    MOTHER_NAME
--------------------------------
1     Henry          Sarah
2     Martin         Rebecca
3     Martin         Nancy
```

I want to get all of the names in the table. I know I can do a union to do this:

```
(SELECT FATHER_NAME FROM MY_TABLE)
UNION
(SELECT MOTHER_NAME FROM MY_TABLE)
```

However, in my real table there are 15 columns I need to union and the query is obviously taking awhile (approximately 12 seconds). And I still need to do joins on these names, etc. Is there any other alternative to doing unions?

FYI: I am using Oracle.

Comment: Our servers are in the process of moving from 10g to 11g. So might be either

Comment: Have you thought of doing selects and joins into a temporary table, then do the union.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Oracle 11g, you can use the `UNPIVOT` function:

```
select id, value, col
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value for col in (FATHER_NAME, MOTHER_NAME) -- other columns will go here
) u;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86f7d/4)

Or you can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` the difference is you will not get `DISTINCT` values:

```
select id, FATHER_NAME value, 'FATHER_NAME' col
from yourtable
union all
select id, MOTHER_NAME value, 'MOTHER_NAME' col
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/86f7d/3)

The `UNION` might be slower due to it attempting to get the `DISTINCT` values.

Comment: Looks like we're on 10g, so UNPIVOT is not recognized. And the `UNION ALL` does not seem to decrease the speed by much. But thanks.

Comment: @blueffet: Could your query be turned into a materialized view?

Comment: @ypercube I don't have the ability to test it (no Oracle instance) but I think it might be able to be a materialized view.  Oracle 10g had them

Comment: While it didn't solve my problem, it looks viable for 11G. I found the solution to my problem via http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034983/maximize-database-view-with-multiple-or-statement

Comment: @bluefeet, can you include other possible pros and cons of `UnPivot` and `UNION`/`UNION ALL`?